# shorthand property name with *this*

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, language-lawyer

The following code fails

```js
let x = {this}
```

Why I cannot use shorthand property name with **this**?

---

error messages from browsers

> chrome  66.0.3359.117 : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
>
> firefox 59.0.1 : this is an invalid identifier
>
> edge 41.16299.371.0 : The use of a keyword for an identifier is invalid

I don't quite get what these messages say.

---

Just to make it clear, the following code runs fine

```js
let x = 5
let y = {x}
let z = {this:this}

console.log({x,y,z})
```

Comment: Because **this** is a keyword, like **function, if, for**, etc ... If you add value, then it becomes a key.

Comment: not sure but it seems `{}` creates an object literal and inside object `this` always refer to its own object, which is undefined here

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina I cannot use `function` `if` `for` for object. but `this` really refers to a object. and I don't see *why* it's forbidden

Comment: @brk the second part is just for reference. my question is on first snip. or the first snip runs without error in your environment?

Comment: `this` return this: `Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}`
You can try to put this value into your `let x = { Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …} }`

Comment: I think this is just how object literal syntax works.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina that was never the question

Comment: @Luca, I just want to show him what excactly happen, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Also, i just want to add, because `this` is a contextual keyword which references the current object in the scope. I think it is best and safe to pass or assigned its value first to a variable.

Comment: Didn't this used to be the case for the regular object initializer syntax? The 2nd code snippet would not have worked on really old browsers, though I'm not sure if that was a bug or a wrong interpretation of the spec by those browsers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[According to the ECMA spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) (I have put in bold what is important):

> ### [12.2.6 Object Initializer](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer)
>
> `NOTE 1 An object initializer is an expression describing the initialization of an Object, written in a form resembling a literal. It is a list of zero or more pairs of property keys and associated values, enclosed in curly brackets. The values need not be literals; they are evaluated each time the object initializer is evaluated.`
>
> #### Syntax
>
> - **ObjectLiteral[Yield] :**
>
>   - { }
>   - **{ PropertyDefinitionList[?Yield] }**
>   - { PropertyDefinitionList[?Yield] , }
> - PropertyDefinitionList[Yield] :
>
>   - **PropertyDefinition[?Yield]**
>   - PropertyDefinitionList[?Yield] , PropertyDefinition[?Yield]
> - PropertyDefinition[Yield] :
>
>   - **IdentifierReference[?Yield]**
>   - CoverInitializedName[?Yield]
>   - PropertyName[?Yield] : AssignmentExpression[In, ?Yield]
>   - MethodDefinition[?Yield]
> - PropertyName[Yield] :
>
>   - LiteralPropertyName
>   - ComputedPropertyName[?Yield]
> - LiteralPropertyName :
>
>   - IdentifierName
>   - StringLiteral
>   - NumericLiteral
> - ComputedPropertyName[Yield] :
>     -[ AssignmentExpression[In, ?Yield] ]
>
>   - CoverInitializedName[Yield] :
>   - IdentifierReference[?Yield] Initializer[In, ?Yield]
> - Initializer[In, Yield] :
>
>   - = AssignmentExpression[?In, ?Yield]
>
> `NOTE 2 MethodDefinition is defined in 14.3.`
>
> `NOTE 3 In certain contexts, ObjectLiteral is used as a cover grammar for a more restricted secondary grammar. The CoverInitializedName production is necessary to fully cover these secondary grammars. However, use of this production results in an early Syntax Error in normal contexts where an actual ObjectLiteral is expected.`

---

> ### [12.1 Identifiers](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-identifiers)
>
> #### Syntax
>
> - **IdentifierReference[Yield] :**
>
>   - **Identifier**
>   - [~Yield] yield
> - BindingIdentifier[Yield] :
>
>   - Identifier
>   - [~Yield] yield
> - LabelIdentifier[Yield] :
>
>   - Identifier
>   - [~Yield] yield
> - **Identifier :**
>
>   - IdentifierName **but not ReservedWord**

What this means is that in the shorthand `let x = {`*Identifier*`}` does not permit reserved words as *Identifier*. And `this` is a reserved word, look at [11.6.2 Reserved Words](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words) and onward.
On the other hand we see that the expanded way of writing it is different:
`let x = {`*PropertyName*`:`*AssignmentExpression*`}` where *PropertName* is either *ComputedPropertyName* or *LiteralPropertyName* wich is *IdentifierName* that does not exclude the reserved words. Thus `let x = {this: this}` or `let x = {class: 10}` is no problem.
It does not, however, explain why this is so, maybe it would complicate the grammar or make it ambiguous?

Comment: I have expanded the explanation at the end to try to make it easier to understand.

Comment: thanks you again. and it's now clear what firefox and edge's error message says. I have one (not that related) question though. what's the `[in]`  `[Yield]` and `[?Yield]` means?

Comment: I have no idea... O_o Maybe somebody else?

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen on SO up to date. Well done (+1)

Answer (score 6):

`this` in Javascript is a keyword (not a variable), thus it has no name.

In case of `{ x }`, x has a name, "x", and it's value.

But `{ this }`, `this` has no name. `this` just represents a proper value when a code is interpreted.

Comment: I would think `{this}` would be treat as `{this:this}` and the  value is used only to second *this*.

Comment: @appleapple Enable ES2015 support (little babble tick in snippet to the left) and it will work in the snippet exactly as you expect. This would indicate that current browsers do not support this feature for `this` yet.

Comment: @Nope I would guess babel compile it to `{this:this}`, I'm not sure if it is correct, thought.

Comment: It is not valid according to the spec (see my answer)

Comment: @appleapple Yes, that is how the expansion works in general, but it treats the first `this` as a property name ("IdentifierName") and the second `this` as a variable name ("Identifier") - which it isn't.